# osx install binary packages

Tags: catkin, build, binaries, osx, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!
I've recently installed ROS Indigo on OS X 10.10.4, exists any way to install packages like in Ubuntu (sudo apt-get install rose-indigo-…)

Or may I always download the package and build my workspace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216202/osx-install-binary-packages/) by [silth](https://answers.ros.org/users/23638/silth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no way to do this like in Ubuntu with one command.

You'll need to download the packages you want and build them. Either by adding them to your existing workspace or by creating a new one.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silth](https://answers.ros.org/users/23638/silth/) on 2015-08-24**:
Thank you for the answer William, that's the way I was doing it. And I should continue…

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2015-09-10**:
Is there a way to automatically resolve dependency between the packages? I mean I can automatically download all in one go?